# Aplicação de classe de CSS após clique na LABEL e também no CHECKBOX

Tags: html, jquery, css

tenho uma dúvida aparentemente simples, mas como sou designer (e não DEV) estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver e não encontro a solução... tentei encontrar algo parecido por aqui, mas não achei...

Fiz uma simulação do que tenho, aqui: 
https://codepen.io/msales78/pen/bGbPrJo

Qual é o problema? Após clicar na LABEL, o elemento é riscado, pois a classe "on" é adicionada, mas eu preciso que funcione TAMBÉM ao se clicar no checkbox, mas isso não ocorre... como poderia obter esse efeito?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta acrescentar outro seletor para o `input`, e no click buscar o `label`.

Para isso use `parent()`, para chegar ao `li` e em seguida algo como `find('label')` para encontrar o elemento e aplicar o estilo, assim:

```
$("ul.check-item li input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
      if ($(this).parent().find("label").hasClass("on")) {
        $(this).parent().find("label").removeClass('on');
      } else{
        $(this).parent().find("label").addClass('on');
      } 
    });
```

Também é possível buscar o label usando `closest()` ou `next()` por exemplo.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Ricardo. Entendi agora onde estava errando... :)